# execute spark.sql withColumn function in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am unable to run spark.sql function in withColumn its thorughing me below error

```
inputDF=spark.sql("select * from <tablname>")
def define_executeSql(columnName):
   qry=columnName
   query =f""" explain {qry} """
   result=spark.sql(query)
   return result

explain_UDF=lambda x : define_executeSql(x)
updatedDF=inputDF.withColumn("explain_sql",udf(explain_UDF,StringType())("sql_query"))
updatedDF.show(20,False)
```

Error : tt appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast.

How to resolve this .how we can pass column of dataframe to spark.sql and return value and add into same datamfame in pyspark

Thank you in advance

expecting the spark.sql query result appear in same dataframe in pypspark . above piece of code i tried

Comment: Can you show as how input_df looks like.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Inputdf : id , sql_query , parameters

Comment: Output df : id , sql_query, record count , runtime